# How to check continue internet speed for video streaming in native android app?

Tags: android

I am building a video streaming app. I need help on how I can check the internet speed on one of the app I'm building. I'll have to adjust my video quality based on that, therefore I need to check the speed.

The app I'm building is in Native Android.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys!